# Why i get an error when creating trigger in pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting error when creating this trigger in pgAdmin

```
create table users
(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
email character varying (255) unique not null,
password character varying (12) not null
);
select * from users

insert into users values('arsa', '1234')

---Login Function---
create function login(_email character varying,_password character varying)
return int as
$$
begin
    if(select count(*) from users where email = _email and password = _password) > 0 then
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    end if
end
$$
language plpsql

----Test Function----
select * from login('Admin','admin')
```

When I press the save button this message come out

ERROR: syntax error at or near "create"
LINE 6: create table users

Comment: Given that the error says: `LINE 6: create table users` I going to say the cause is something before LINE 6. Also since I do not see any of your statements(other then the CREATE TABLE) ending with `;` I'm going to go out on a limb and say you have statement you are not showing before the `CREATE TABLE ..` statement that is not properly terminated with a `;`. FYI, in the function statements need to be terminated with a `;` not a `:`.

Comment: In addition to what Adrian wrote: I don't see anything related to a trigger in that code

Comment: i already change the :  to  ; but the error is not fixed, and I didn't have any statement before the CREATE TABLE.

Comment: The ERROR thinks so, it is getting LINE 6 from somewhere. Best guess is there is some statement stuck in the buffer of whatever you are using to run the above. Also you need to add `;` to the other statements otherwise you will get errors when the script gets to them.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the missing statement terminators (;) previously mentioned, your script has a fatal error, the insert statement will fail. Why? Since you did not list the column names to be inserted the values **must** include every column including id, and they must be in the order defined. You cannot have a auto incrementing column and not specify its value unless you specify the columns to insert (or use the default keyword in the proper position). So you need

```
insert into users(email, password) values('arsa', '1234');
insert into users values(default, 'abc', 'def');
```

It seems the purpose of your function is not to perform Login as implied by the name but validate the credentials. In this case you can reduce it to a single SQL statement. No counting, no count checking, just a single select (yea, with subselect):

```
create or replace 
 function is_valid_user(_email character varying
                       ,_password character varying
                       )
  returns boolean  
 language sql 
as $$
    select exists (select null 
                     from users 
                    where email = _email 
                      and password = _password
                  ); 
$$;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=66b2954e97ced635642c519b2c65fa45).

If you actually need a trigger you will also need a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-trigger.html) and a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html) on the table itself